# iphone QuickTime error

Tags: iphone, quicktime

I try to play simple mp3 file iPhone simulator in my Mac.
I use AVFoundation.framework and AVAudioPlayer.
In one of my mac everything is OK, but in onother Mac, when i build app ( simulator 2.2 ) give me error:

Error is:

```
Error loading /Library/QuickTime/DivX Decoder.component/Contents/MacOS/DivX Decoder:  dlopen(/Library/QuickTime/DivX Decoder.component/Contents/MacOS/DivX Decoder, 262): Symbol not found: _SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser
 Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
 Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.2.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you do have DivX, but it's missing a symbol, and you need to delete
/Library/QuickTime/DivX Decoder.component

Comment: Yup, I ran into that one a few times. DivX doesn't agree with the use of QuickTime in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have the DivX Decoder bundle (DivX Decoder.component) installed in your other Mac.

I checked on my mac, and I don't have it either, so it something you installed on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the DivX codec isn't installed on that other mac.  [Install DivX](http://www.divx.com/en/products/software/mac/divx) and you should be all set.